# Having trouble understanding data notations. (zero suppression, fixed signs)

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

I'm learning RPG, well trying to anyway. And there's this practice chart on how printer spacing charts work. I'm having trouble understanding how these notations actually work. Can someone help explain this better?

Here's the chart for reference:

[image: Data Chart]

Here's what I understand:
`A = 98100`
`B = 01254`
`C = 31,331`
(and then I get confused with the 0's)
`D = 00,01?`
And now I'm totally lost.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

The notation used on a printer spacing chart is purely arbitrary. It is a piece of paper with a grid of fixed character positions that means something to the person who created it. I haven't used on for years, preferring to just write notes on a sample report printed in a courier font. The purpose of the courier font is to get a fixed width font for counting characters. Each person does it differently though, and these codes do not translate directly to edit codes or edit words in RPG. For numbers I always wrote a `#` or a `9` to mean a digit, and I always assumed zero suppression. If I did not want zero suppression, I would use a `0` to indicate a digit. I suspect that in this case the `0` indicates zero suppression to the position of the `0`. `$` and `-` signs embedded in the pattern could indicate floating `$` or `-` signs. `,` embedded in he pattern would indicate a thousands separator while a `.` would indicate the position of the decimal point. `DB` might indicate that a `CR` is used in place of the negative sign, though I would expect a `CR` instead of a `DB`. I don't know of any way to print a positive number symbol via edit words, or edit codes. It may be possible to do using custom edit codes, but I don't know about that. So, given this maybe the chart should be:

```
A = 98100
B = 01254
C = 31,331
D =     10  Zero suppression, thousands separators not printed if not needed
E =  1,000
F =         Zero suppressed, or maybe just displays 0
G = $   872  Fixed currency symbol with zero suppression
H =    $298  Floating Currency symbol implies zero suppression
I =      $0
J =  -7,254  Floating negative sign
K =    -451
L =    923CR
M = 91,486  No sign in the pattern
N =         See F
```